# Intuition behind the relationship between conjugation on a Lie group and the Lie bracket

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, intuition

As I learn more about the correspondence between Lie groups and Lie algebras, the underlying structure of a Lie algebra feels more and more mysterious to me. It seems that the Lie bracket is absolutely necessary to do anything with the Lie algebra, but for a while I had no idea what it was even doing.

Recently, however, I found an interpretation which seems to get close. Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\frak{g}$ the underlying Lie algebra, treated as the tangent space at the identity $e$. Define the conjugation map $\gamma_g: G \to G$ for each $g$, and define $\text{Ad}: G \to \text{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ so that $\text{Ad}(g) = (\gamma_g)_{*e}$. Further, differentiate this map at $e$ to get $\text{Ad}_{*e} = \text{ad}: \mathfrak{g} \to \text{End}(\mathfrak{g})$. We define $[X, Y] = \text{ad}_X(Y)$. According to this definition, the Lie bracket is the infinitesimal version of conjugation; roughly speaking, it tells you how much the infinitesimal $Y$ changes if you conjugate by the infinitesimal $X$.

This gets *so* close to being a satisfying explanation! There's just one, very important, loose end: how is mere *conjugation* able to completely classify the (local) structure of Lie groups? It seems completely unreasonable to me that such a specific operation should be able to generate every element of the group. I've tried analysing the proofs of theorems in more detail, for example the classification of simply connected Lie algebras and the BCH-formula, but they all seem to either lose me in screeds of arbitrary choices or use results which aren't related to the adjoint representation.

My question is therefore the following: what is the significance of conjugation in the study of Lie algebras? How, intuitively, can we obtain the structure of a Lie group just from the way that conjugation acts near the identity?

Comment: What is 'mere' about conjugation? It is perhaps the most natural action apart from the simple right and left actions. Crucially, unlike those, it preserves the identity so descends to a natural action on the Lie algebra. Note that the operation in no way generates the group but that is not what we are asking of it.

Comment: @Callum I think that's getting to the heart of my question. You say "it is perhaps the most natural action," but I really don't see it. Yes, it does preserve the identity, but there are a lot of such actions. Yes, it's simple, but that doesn't mean it's significant. What I'm looking for is a more fundamental understanding of the operation, in that it directly solves a problem we have or models something we care about, and a (rough) explanation of how this leads to whatever classifying/generative power it has.

Comment: What other such actions? Do these actions actually use the inherent group structure? It's hard for me to imagine another group action (aside from trivial changes) on the group itself that has that many nice properties and can be defined inherently on any group. For example conjugation always gives you automorphisms. You study this even in finite groups where we are not thinking about Lie algebras.

Comment: The only surprising link here is that the Lie bracket defined in terms of vector fields precisely matches the derivative of the Adjoint representation and you can see this by considering what the flow given by such a vector field looks like (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440724/relation-between-definitions-of-lie-bracket-via-adjoint-representation-and-via-l))

Comment: @Callum I was thinking about outer automorphisms, but you are correct that these can't be defined in any group. Even still, this characterisation of conjugation is deeply displeasing to me; it feels like we are saying "we can't think of any other operations, so they must be special." In this light, the usefulness of the Lie bracket feels more like an accident, like we just happened to be able to get all the information we needed about the local structure from the operations we knew (as opposed to these operations somehow being "fundamental" to the local structure).

Comment: Not at all. It's fundamental because it is defined in direct terms of the group action. The only more fundamental actions are the simple left and right actions but they, as discussed, aren't directly relevant for this. Then because it is acts as automorphisms of the group it descends to automorphisms of the Lie algebra etc. The Lie bracket is not an accident. It is a general feature of all vector fields, the only 'accident' is that it coincides with the derivative of the Adjoint rep